# How to insert a large number of elements into MySQL database by using the python package MySQLdb?

Tags: python, mysql

If I want to insert a new data into a table, I should type the code like this `"""INSERT INTO AB1 (`COL1`,`COL2`) VALUES ('%s','%s')""" % (element1,element2)`

What if I need to insert a large number of elements, I can't type these elements one by one manually.

Actually, the data what I want to save is an array(is a vector with 90 elements) calculated by python, and I want to save it into MySQL row by row.

Comment: You'll want to look at the [executemany method of the cursor](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#executemany). Unfortunately, MySQLdb is poorly documented, but there's an example at the end of the [Some Examples](http://mysqlclient.readthedocs.io/user_guide.html#some-examples) section. Please do not use string interpolation to build your queries.

Comment: Please **do not use % formatting** on SQL strings. It will allow SQL injections. Always use the method provided by you DB adapter to parameterize SQL queries.